# Run fast cgi program through web browser

Tags: apache, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have created a hello FastCGI prog in C

```
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count;
void initialize(void)
{
  count=0;
}
int main(void)
{
  initialize();

  while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0)
  {
    printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n"
     "\r\n"
     "<title>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</title>"
     "<h1>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</h1>"
     "Request number %d running on host <i>%s</i>\n",
      ++count, getenv("REMOTE_HOST"));
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Then I compiled the program using "gcc -o hello1 hello1.c -lfcgi"

This created "hello1" executable file in my home directory (in ubuntu)
When I ran this file, I got output as:

```
Content-type: text/html

<title>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</title><h1>FastCGI Hello! (C, fcgi_stdio library)</h1>Request number 1 running on host <i>(null)</i>
```

I want to run this file from firefox. Since I am new to this, I dont have any idea about it. Can any one, provide me with detailed ans, what all steps I need to follow to run it through web browser. 
I tried typing the URL as "http://localhost/fcgi-bin/hello1" after copying the 'hello1" file to /etc/apache/fcgi-bin/hello1.fcgi but it gave 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You'd still need to include the `.fcgi` extension on the url:

```
http://localhost/fcgi-bin/hello1.fcgi
```

Comment: I have tried this option also, but got 'The requested URL /fcgi-bin/hello1.fcgi was not found on this server.


I guess we need to do some configuration, but dnt know what

Comment: Check the Apache error log, it'll say exactly what path the server was checking for your file. Is /fcgi-bin a real directory on your server, or a ScriptAlias/Alias type construct? You may need to configure that in Apache so it knows where to look.

Comment: yeah, this worked. Thanks. 
But now instead of running fcgi file, its asking me to save it as it is a binary file.

Comment: Then most likely Apache's not been told that .fcgi files should be treated as fcgi binaries. `SetHandler fcgid-script` should be somewhere in your httpd.conf's section for the fcgi directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help
Issue got resolved, I had not made entry of fcgi files in sites-enabled/000-default. We need to add following lines:
<Directory "/usr/lib/fcgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
     </Directory>